# Standard ShareDialog can only send ShareLinkContent but not ShareMediaContent

Tags: android, facebook, share, fbsdksharedialog

While using standard `ShareDialog` the app can only send `ShareLinkContent` but not `ShareMediaContent`.

According to the [description](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android/)  the app should send both.

```
ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)
```

result=true

```
ShareDialog.canShow(ShareMediaContent.class)
```

result=false

Answer (score 0):

```
ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)
```

always return true regardless theirs facebook app installed

```
ShareDialog.canShow(ShareMediaContent.class)
```

only return true if their facebook app installed